# cron job unexpected EOF error

Tags: cron, eof

I really don't know anything about cron jobs but I am trying to get this to work for a brokerage companies website I am working on.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

I have been given an xml datafeed that I am trying to update my own xml from.
I was given the following xml.sh file

```
cd `dirname $0`
echo `date` "Importing boats" >> /home/content/91/11071291/html/used-boats/import.log

curl -o /home/content/91/11071291/html/used-boats/horizon.xml "https://I-hid-this-address-incase-ishouldnt-share-on-stackoverflow.com?status=on" >> import.log 
SUCCESS=$?
echo $SUCCESS
if [ $SUCCESS -ne 0 ]; then
echo "Data Download failed. Exiting"
exit $SUCCESS
fi

home/content/91/11071291/html/used-boats/import-local-xml.php >> /home/content/91/11071291/html/used-boats/import.log
```

when running the cron job I always get this error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that a double-quote character (`"`) was not matched.

The quotes all match in what your question shows, so either you've transcribed something incorrectly, or the error lies within the definition of the cron job. Use `crontab -e` to edit your cron table, and double-check that to make sure all the quotes match.